# spring return view did not working after using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I have a problem in my web application.

I want to pass the input tag value by GET method. I cannot found proper thing so used jquery ajax method.

my jsp has no form tags
here is my jsp code

```
<input type="text" id="input-number" />
<button id="search-button" onclick="getSearch()"> SEARCH </button>
```

The 'getSearch()' method is defined in .js file like this

```
function getSearch(){
var number = $("input-number").val();
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url:"test/search/" + number });
```

and finally my Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test/search/{number}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSearchNumber(@PathVariable String number, Model model){
  model.addAttribute("...", ...);
  return "test/numberValue";
```

the numberValue.jsp included in test directory
the directory have no problem. cause when i using POST method without ajax just form tag the servlet mapping is correctly working. And the PathVariable is also correct I already check the value.
I want to this page using GET method.

The phenomenon is similar to refresh. And no error message.

The weird thing, i put the url in chrome browser "test/search/1234" this is working!!

could you solve my problem?

Comment: Works as expected. If you are using ajax then also use ajax to handle the response. Something is returned but you are happily ignoring it. Your ajax call just ignores the response, hence nothing will change.

Comment: What do you mean I ignore something?
jsp button event -> ajax function call -> controller url mapping then return -> again return to ajax function? Is it flow of request?
could you explain or give me a clue to solve this problem?

Comment: Ajax is a http request and response in the background... AJAX - Asynchronous JavaScript and XML... The key here is background and async. Yes you are calling your controller, which does return a response but because you ignore that response on the client side it appears as if nothing is happening... ajax 101 that is.

Comment: I edit my controller and ajax function
append @ResponseBody on the Controller method and
append success: function(data){ return data;} in ajax function But, it doesn't work... am i wrong?

Comment: And then what... Return to what... Again you are doing nothing, screen wise with your request.

Comment: I solved this problem another way.(using Spring)
thank you for your advise :)